# Transparent png as background-image

Tags: css

I'm having some issues while using a transparent PNG image as a background image via CSS.

This is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKj7E.png

And this is my CSS code:

```
#userBar {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('../img/userbarbg.png');
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    float: left;
    height: 36px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What's wrong? The borders? Apply `border-radius` to fix the issue, eg. `border-radius:5px;`. If `box-shadow` is supported, then also `border-radius`.

Comment: Well... that png's angles should be transparent by their own, but they are black instead :S

Comment: @MaterMorbi ...(offtopic) you know that you can do: `background: #000 url(someImage.jpg) no-repeat 20px 20px` , where the first 20px is 'left' and the next is 'top' background-position? :)

Comment: @roXon Thanks, no i didn't know, but i appreciate your hint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re seeing the `box-shadow` behind the background image. The element is still a rectangular box as far as the browser is concerned, so that box shape is what it uses to generate the shadow. You’ll need to specify a `border-radius` (including the various browser prefixes, `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-o-`, etc.) that matches that of the corners on your transparent background so the shadow will have the same shape as the content it's behind.

Comment: Thank you :) I thought there was something wrong with the images.